# Swift NSTimer didn't work

Tags: swift, nstimer

I make a "Command Line Tool", and I need use NSTimer.
I start the timer, but it doesn't work...

```
import Foundation

class ct : NSObject {
    func start() {
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func update() {
        println("test timer");
    }
}
var a = ct();
a.start()

while(true) { sleep(10000000) }
```

Comment: Try to make the timer a member of the class instead.

Comment: Could you make an example?

Comment: var timer : NSTimer? above start function and then in start function do like this time = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true), if ifs not working try to add it to currentRunloop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSTimer` needs a run loop to work properly, a CLI doesn't have/need one by default.

Call

```
CFRunLoopRun()
```

to start the run loop and

```
CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent())
```

to stop it and don't forget to return appropriate return values.