# Command Line Tool using Timer() in Swift

Tags: swift, command-line, timer

I'm writing a command line tool and want to handle various inputs and also want to fire a Timer() on a specific command and also stop it on an other command.
Unfortunately this does not work

```
import Foundation

class timerTest : NSObject {


var myTimer : Timer? = nil
func startTimer() {
    myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: {_ in
        print("Hello")
    })

    let runLoop = RunLoop()
    runLoop.add(myTimer!, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
    RunLoop.current.run()
}

func stopTimer() {
    myTimer?.invalidate()
}


}
var a = timerTest()

print("Ready")

while true {
    var keyboard = FileHandle.standardInput
    var inputData = keyboard.availableData
    var string = NSString(data: inputData, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
    string = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    if string == "timer" { a.startTimer() }
    if string == "stop" { a.stopTimer() }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at the following SO thread, it answers your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140470/swift-nstimer-didnt-work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift NSTimer didn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140470/swift-nstimer-didnt-work)

Comment: Adding the timer to the runloop successfully runs the timer, but it seems that I now cannot interact with the app any more as the while true loop does not run any more. I need to enter a command to invalidate the timer

Comment: Can you update the code to show how you've modified it? I can take a look and see what might be going on ...

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
import Foundation

var shouldKeepRunning = true

class CLIInput:NSObject {
    var inputTimer:Timer? = nil
    var myTimer:Timer? = nil

    func getInput() {
        inputTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:1, repeats:false, block: {_ in
            var input = readLine()!
            input = input.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            print("Input: \(input)")
            if input == "timer" {
                print("Start timer")
                self.myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:1, repeats: true, block: {_ in
                    print("Hello")
                })
            }
            if input == "stop" {
                print("Stop timer")
                self.myTimer?.invalidate()
                self.myTimer = nil
            }
            if input == "exit"  {
                print("Time to exit")
                self.inputTimer?.invalidate()
                self.inputTimer = nil
                shouldKeepRunning = false
                return
            }
            // Otherwise, set up timer again
            self.getInput()
        })
    }
}

print("Start")
var cli = CLIInput()
cli.getInput()
let theRL = RunLoop.current
while shouldKeepRunning && theRL.run(mode: .defaultRunLoopMode, before: .distantFuture) { }
```

However, any time you are waiting for input from standard input, you'll find that your timer block output does not display because output is blocked till your input is complete. As long as your timer process does not need to do any output, the above might (or might not, depending on your requirements) work ...

Comment: Unfortunately I need the timer to do timer based output on the stdout while waiting for new commands to stdin :(

Comment: I am not sure that you can get it to work like that since if you are waiting on stdinput, if the program also outputs to stdoutput, what you see on screen will get jumbled up between input and output. Have you seen any examples of CLI apps which work the way you want?

Comment: To be honest: no. So I think I have to redesign my app

Comment: Good luck! If there's anything I can do to help, do let me know :)